# C# Using Equals method in a generic list fails

Tags: c#, templates, generics, equals

I have a project where I have class State which uses templates.
I have a class Cell, and I use it as State, so State holds a Cell as genericState.
Now I have a generic function which checks if two instances are equal.
Problem is, it never leaves the State Equals method to Cell Equals method.

```
public class State<T>
{
    public T genericState;  //in my case T is a cell
    public State(T cellState) // CTOR
    {
        this.genericState = cellState;  
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {            
        return genericState.Equals((obj as State<T>).genericState); 
    } //never leaves
}
```

and code of Class Cell, in which it never gets:

```
public class Cell
{
    public int row, col;
    public bool visited;
    public char value;
    public bool Equals(Cell other)   //never gets here
    {            
       return other != null && other.row == row && other.col == col;    
    }
 }
```

I don't understand why it never gets to Equal method of Cell. What could be wrong with the code?

Comment: I think maybe [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx) might help you

Comment: @Squirrel5853 yours link isn't valid anymore, it's just redirecting to other page :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your code does not know that `T` has a special method

```
bool Equals<T>(T other)
```

It thinks that it should be calling `Cell`'s override of `Equals(object)`, which your code does not override.

Fixing this is simple: add `IEquatable<Cell>` to the list of interfaces implemented by `Cell`, and add a constraint on `T` to ensure that it implements `IEquatable<T>`:

```
public class State<T> where T : IEquatable<T> {
    ... // The rest of the code remains the same
}
...
public class Cell : IEquatable<Cell> {
    ... // The rest of the code remains the same
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should override `object.Equals` to defer to this `Equals`:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as Cell);
```

And if you are overriding `object.Equals` then you also need to override `object.GetHashCode()`:

```
public override int GetHashCode() => row * 31 + col;
```

Further to this, for better performance you could have `Cell` implement `IEquatable<Cell>`, and in your `State<T>.Equals` use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`. This will be better because `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` uses `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)` when implemented, falling back to `object.Equals(object)` when that isn't available.

Comment: where should i put this piece of code? but this way I ignore the generic templates, no?

Comment: Override in all types, which can fill T at compile type in the generic template, it will automatically pick up

Comment: Which, the use of `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`? You use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(genericState, (obj as State<T>).genericState)` instead of calling `genericState.Equals((obj as State<T>).genericState)`.

Answer (score 0):

`genericState.Equals`is the equality method derived from `object`. In your `Cell` class, you are not overriding `object.Equals(object)`, so your equality method (`Cell.Equals(Cell)`) is not being called, but instead, `Cell.Equals(object)` is being called. So what you can do to fix this is change your `Cell` class to override the default equality method:

```
public class Cell
{
    public int row, col;
    public bool visited;
    public char value;
    public override bool Equals(object other)   //never gets here
    {            
       if(!(other is Cell)) return false;
       return other != null && other.row == row && other.col == col;    
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this method will help you, it should to handle also the situations when `obj` or `genericState` could be `null`.

```
public override bool Equals(object? obj)
{
    return obj is State<T> state && object.Equals(state.genericState, this.genericState);
}
```